# What is the recommendation to reuse GraphServiceClient in Microsoft Graph .Net SDK?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I realized Microsoft Graph .Net SDK is using `HttpClient` class.

```
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/HttpProvider.cs
```

Microsoft's own documentation recommends reuse of `HttpClient` instances as much as possible instead of spinning up a new instance per request which may lead to exhausting the connection pool and `SocketException`s eventually.

Is there a similar recommendation, to reuse `GraphServiceClient` as much as possible? Is there any particular concern with instantiating a new `GraphServiceClient` per request?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am not aware of any recommendation, but if you look at the code from both the `GraphServiceClient` as the underlying `BaseClient`, there is not state kept. Only the incoming or defaulted [`HttpProvider`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/HttpProvider.cs), and there is the problem. If you rely on the `GraphServiceClient` generating a new `HttpProvider` (and thus a new `HttpClient`) each and every time, you have the same problem as with creating multiple `HttpClient` instances.

So if you are recreating clients, you should at least provide it with a cached `HttpProvider`. And then, it doesn't hurt much to keep the entire client in cache.

Comment: Yup.  Same rules as HttpClient.  Try and reuse the instance so that we can take advantage of existing TCP connections.

Comment: This saved my life :) My api performance got improved by ~50% after i am using HttpProvider as a singleton object.